# How to Get a parent category name in productlist.tpl file in prestashop 1.5?

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I would like to get a parent category id of my products in product listing or category pages.

http://wholesale-genie.com/

I have tried following code in product-list.tpl file but no luck.

I have used version 1.5.x

**Parent category name :{$product->id_category_default}**

So please any one help me would be better?

Answer (score 2):

You must use a dot instead of an arrow `{$product.id_category_default}`